# Flask app intended to download a file is downloading a zero-byte (empty) file

Tags: python, html, image, flask

Newby here so please be patient and gentle. I am trying to learn a bit of tensorflow which is complicated by the fact that I suck at python so I'm trying to learn both at the same time.  It's going about as well as you'd expect.  As a fun exercise I thought I'd build a tensorflow image recognition model that can recognize fly fishing flies from a photo (my father-in-law gave me a zillion flies but I don't know what any of them are - hence the exercise).

So my simple tensorflow model is working well locally but I'm trying to migrate it to a web app (locally first - hopefully online eventually) using Flask (which I also don't know - get the pattern here).

So the objective is to present a web page that asks the user (me) to upload an image of the fly from a local file and then submit it to the engine to recognize it.
[image]

The image recognition is working (amazingly) but I would like to display the fly image and this is not working.  I am just getting a generic "uploaded photo" icon.

[image]

In addition, the uploaded file is supposed to be stored in a local directory but the file that is being stored is empty (zero bytes) although the file name is correct.

[image]

Again, my knowledge of Python is simply terrible so I'm pretty sure I'm doing something dumb. Can anyone help me?

(also it's pretty clear I don't know how to insert code into a stack-overflow question!

Thank you kind hive!!!

Code follows for

FlyFinderWeb.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, send_from_directory
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
from io import BytesIO

class_names = ['Pheasant Tail Nymph', 'Wooly Bugger', 'adams dry fly', 'elk hair caddis']
img_height = 180
img_width = 180

# Load the saved Keras model
keras_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('Fly_classifer_keras_model')

app = Flask(__name__)
UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'uploads'
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_photo():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'photo' not in request.files:
            return redirect(request.url)
        
        photo = request.files['photo']
        
        if photo.filename == '':
            return redirect(request.url)
        
        if photo:
            filename = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], photo.filename)
            photo.save(filename)
            return redirect(url_for('display_photo', filename=photo.filename))
    
    return render_template('upload.html')

@app.route('/download/<path:filename>')
def download_photo(filename):
    return send_from_directory(
        os.path.abspath(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']), 
        filename
    )

@app.route('/display/<filename>')
def display_photo(filename):
    print(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))  
    return render_template('display.html', filename=filename)


@app.route('/recognize', methods=['POST'])
def recognize_fly():
    if 'photo' not in request.files:
        return "No file part"
    
    photo = request.files['photo']
    
    if photo.filename == '':
        return "No selected file"

    
    # Convert FileStorage to BytesIO
    photo_bytes = BytesIO(photo.read())
    
    # Load the TensorFlow model
    model = keras_model
    
    img = tf.keras.utils.load_img(photo_bytes, target_size=(img_height, img_width))
    img_array = tf.keras.utils.img_to_array(img)
    img_array = tf.expand_dims(img_array, 0)
    
    predictions = model.predict(img_array)
    class_index = np.argmax(predictions[0])
    class_name = class_names[class_index]
    score = tf.nn.softmax(predictions[0])

   
    recognition_results = f"I think what you have here is a {class_name}. I'm {100*np.max(score):.2f}% sure of this (but I could be wrong!)."
    
    filename = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], photo.filename)
    print("Photo size:", len(photo.read()))  # Print the size of the photo content
    print("Uploaded File:", photo.filename)
    photo.save(filename)
    return render_template('display.html', filename=photo.filename, recognition_results=recognition_results)


app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=True) #automatically restart server if changes are detected  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Display.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Display Photo</title>
    <style>
        .image-container {
            text-align: center;
            margin-bottom: 20px; /* Added margin for spacing */
        }
        .image-container img {
            max-width: 100%;
            max-height: 400px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Uploaded Photo</h1>

    <div class="image-container">
        <img src="{{ url_for('download_photo', filename=filename) }}" alt="Uploaded Photo">
    </div>





    <h2>Fly Recognition Results:</h2>
    <p>{{ recognition_results }}</p>

    <p>Would you like to repeat another?</p>
    <a href="{{ url_for('upload_photo') }}">Upload Another</a>
</body>
</html>
```

upload.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Upload and Display Photo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Upload a Photo Please 5.0</h1>

    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ url_for('recognize_fly') }}">
        <input type="file" name="photo" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit image to my big Machine Learning brain to see if I can figure out what fly it is">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

See above... I tried and it created a zero byte file instead of downloading the entire file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you made multiple `photo.read()` calls in the handler function `recognize_fly` which will cause the pointer reads through the photo file and leaves the read cursor at the end of the file (with nothing left to read). To reset the cursor for later `read()` calls and allow the image to be uploaded/rendered, you should use `photo.seek(0)` after you called `photo.read()` to return the read cursor to the start of the file since the `photo.save(filename)` also use `read()` under the hood to save the file. You can read more details [here](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/bltin-file-objects.html)

```
@app.route('/recognize', methods=['POST'])
def recognize_fly():
    if 'photo' not in request.files:
        return "No file part"
    
    photo = request.files['photo']
    
    if photo.filename == '':
        return "No selected file"

    
    # Convert FileStorage to BytesIO
    photo_bytes = BytesIO(photo.read())
    photo.seek(0)
    
    # Load the TensorFlow model
    model = keras_model
    
    img = tf.keras.utils.load_img(photo_bytes, target_size=(img_height, img_width))
    img_array = tf.keras.utils.img_to_array(img)
    img_array = tf.expand_dims(img_array, 0)
    
    predictions = model.predict(img_array)
    class_index = np.argmax(predictions[0])
    class_name = class_names[class_index]
    score = tf.nn.softmax(predictions[0])

   
    recognition_results = f"I think what you have here is a {class_name}. I'm {100*np.max(score):.2f}% sure of this (but I could be wrong!)."
    
    filename = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], photo.filename)
    print("Photo size:", len(photo.read()))  # Print the size of the photo content
    photo.seek(0)
    print("Uploaded File:", photo.filename)
    photo.save(filename)
    return render_template('display.html', filename=photo.filename, recognition_results=recognition_results)
```